# Matrix norm equivalence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

If we define $ \|A\| = \max \{|A\cdot \mathbf{t}|:|\mathbf{t}|\leq 1\}.$ is it the same as defining it as $\max \{|A\cdot \mathbf{t}|:|\mathbf{t}|= 1\}$ ? If so, why? The book I'm following uses the first definition and while searching the web for some hints to my question, I encountered this other one.

Any help would be appreciated. ;)

Comment: On (1), the answer is "yes" for linear transformations $A$ on finite dimensional spaces and $|\cdot|$ denotes a vector norm. On infinite dimensional spaces, you need a sup rather than max.

Comment: Thanks for your answer to (1), @JohnD . Could you explain a little more, or give me a link where I could find more info on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of an operator norm is as follows: if $A:V\to W$, then $$\|A\|:=\sup_{v\in V,\,v\not=0}{\|Av\|\over \|v\|}.$$ Here, the numerator is the vector norm on $W$ while the denominator is the vector norm on $V$.

If $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional, this supremum is a maximum (i.e., the least upper bound is attained). Then, by the linearity of $A$ and properties of the (vector) norms,
$$
\sup_{v\in V,\,v\not=0}{\|Av\|\over \|v\|}=\sup_{v\in V,\,v\not=0}\left\|{1\over \|v\|}Av\right\|=\sup_{v\in V,\,v\not=0}\|A(v/\|v\|)\|=\sup_{v\in V,\|v\|=1}\|Av\|.
$$
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to split this into 2 proper questions.